# Safely Using a Browser Key for Google Places API Web Service on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been using the [Google Places API for Android Autocomplete Widget](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) by embedding the `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` into my activity. This works alright, but has several drawbacks for my implementation stemming from the widget's performance and the lack of the *radius* filter that is available in the full [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro).

I'd like to start moving off the *Google Places API for Android* and use the *Google Places API Web Service* instead to get access to the broader filtering options. However, the documentation states the following:

> Note: The Google Places API Web Service does not work with an Android or iOS restricted API key.

This means, I assume, that I have to use either a Browser or Server restricted API Key in my application, but on Android, I understand these options to be less than ideal because it becomes possible to steal the API key.

How can I safely use a Browser API Key within my Android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web service is supposed to be called from your backend server. The API keys for web services support IP address restriction. So, in order to protect an API key that you are going to use with web service requests you should create an intermediate server that will send requests to Google and pass responses back to your Android app. To protect an API key you should use an IP address of your intermediate server.